# Use class methods from controller which is injected in AspNet Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am creating one AspNet Core MVC application where i have used one class which have some methods and those methods uses session to get data also logging the methods to find out if any exception found.

I used below class:

```
public class MyBAL
{       
    private readonly ILogger<FilterBAL> _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
   
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
   
    public MyBAL(ILogger<MyBAL> logger, IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _logger = logger; _configuration = configuration; _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor; _env = env;
        apiHostName = _configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:ApiHostName");
    }
    //Some methods used below to get some session data, get some value from appSettings.json file
}
```

Then i call this from controller which is below:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    #region Log Initialization
    private readonly ILogger<BaseController> _logger;
    #endregion
    #region Private Variables
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
    #endregion
    #region Public variables
    public int sessionTimeoutReminder = 1;
    public int sessionTimeOut = 1;
    StringBuilder mbmenu = new StringBuilder(), lbmenu = new StringBuilder(), sbmenu = new StringBuilder();
    public static bool isLandingScreen;
    #endregion
    
    public BaseController(ILogger<BaseController>logger, IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _logger = logger; _configuration = configuration; _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor; _env = env;
    }
    public ActionResult GetMenu()
    {
      MyBALfb = new MyBAL(_logger, _configuration, _httpContextAccessor, _env);
      
      return PartialView();
    }
}
```

But here while passing parameter of logger getting compile time error like cannot convert baseController.Ilogger to MyBAL.Ilogger.

Note: I am beginner in AspNet Core, Please suggest if my above approach is correct or provide the best solution.

Comment: Did my answer help you solve your problem? If it is solved, please accept it as the answer, otherwise, please tell me your still existing problems.

Answer (score 0):

> But here while passing parameter of logger getting compile time error
> like cannot convert baseController.Ilogger to MyBAL.Ilogger.

This error means that when the MyBAL object is created in BaseController, the first parameter type you substitute is `ILogger<BaseController>`, and in the constructor of the MyBAL class, the first parameter type to receive is `ILogger<MyBAL>`, these two are different types,which causing errors.

If you want the first parameter type of the constructor of the `MyBAL` class to **dynamic** type, then I suggest you `change ILogger<MyBAL> to ILogger<dynamic>`:

```
 public class MyBAL
    {
        private readonly ILogger<dynamic> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

        public MyBAL(ILogger<dynamic> logger, IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _logger = logger; _configuration = configuration; _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor; _env = env;
            apiHostName = _configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:ApiHostName");
        }
        //Some methods used below to get some session data, get some value from appSettings.json file
    }
```